# Do TQFTs give a complete set of invariants of manifolds?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, qa.quantum-algebra, topological-quantum-field-theory

An $n$-dimensional TQFT is a representation of the category $n$Cob of $n$-dimensional cobordisms. TQFTs are important sources of invariants of manifolds, and such invariants are highly computable by cutting and pasting.

**I am curious if TQFTs give a complete set of invariants of manifolds (either in topological category or smooth category).** My impression is that the locality of TQFTs, which enables the computation via cutting and pasting, seems like quite a strong property, so it might be possible that there are two manifolds which cannot be distinguished by any TQFTs.

Comment: You're a bit vague about the exact field theories you're allowing. Can you give more details? But a certain variant does not distinguish smooth 4-manifolds: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503054.

Comment: If you allow TQFTs with arbitrary targets, then there is a universal one, namely the identity functor, which is a complete invariant tautologously. So some comstraints are needed on the target, e.g. that it be linear.

Comment: @skupers Thanks for the reference. I was intentionally vague, as I wanted to know the limitations of TQFTs in general (with a lot of different variants), not a specific version of it, in capturing some information of manifolds. But if I were to be more specific, I am most interested in the TQFTs as defined in the Atiyah's original paper: http://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/TQFT/At.pdf.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, of course. I was assuming that the target is the category of vector spaces. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, is that so clear? Is isomorphism in the bordism category the same as in the category of smooth manifolds?